# How to delete rows from the datastore that our app uses in google appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

All the videos and tutorials show only how to add stuff to the datastore and fetch through the GqlQuery. How to delete stuff from the datastore? Does a 'DELETE FROM mytable WHERE condition' query work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers by systempuntout and Forest are both correct -- however, you may want to know that you can also batch some datastore operations together for higher efficiency (see this [blog post](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/06/10-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about.html) from the App Engine team).

You could modify systempuntout's response like this:

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Foo")
results = q.fetch(10)
db.delete(results)
```

Instead of a roundtrip for each item deleted, it's a single operation to delete the lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

[GQL](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) language is read-only and it is useful for retrieving entities or keys from the App Engine Datastore.

For the `DELETE` Statements you have to use the [delete](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_delete) method provided by the [Datastore API](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html).
An example:

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Foo")
results = q.fetch(10)
for result in results:
    result.delete()
```